# Not able to use an interface since the object is null

Tags: java, android

I have a dialog that contains a button. When I press that button, I want the view of MainActivity to be changed.

I have tried it with an interface but I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
> 'void ch.yourclick.kitt.classes.Popup$IControl.status(boolean)' on a
> null object reference

**Popup.java**

```java
public interface IControl {
    void status(boolean status);
}
public IControl iControl = null;

    @SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "ResourceType"})
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view =  inflater.inflate(_layout, container, false);

        view.findViewById(R.id.turbineStartUp).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            iControl.status(true);
        });
```

**MainActivity.java**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Popup.IControl {
    private final Popup mPopup = new Popup(R.layout.fragment_dialog);

    @Override
    public void status(boolean status) {
        System.out.println(status);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPopup.iControl = this;
```

I don't see why the object is *null*, though I set `mPopup.iControl = this;` in `onCreate()`. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I am not trying to change the view outside of the activity. With `iControl.status(true);` I am trying to inform MainActivity that the view should be changed. Then in MainActivity I am overriding the method `status()` to change the view.  `public IControl iControl` is _null_, that is correct but what about `mPopup.iControl = this;` in MainActivity? It should not be _null_ anymore?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that when the instruction

```
private final Popup mPopup = new Popup(R.layout.fragment_dialog);
```

is executed, it calls the class `Popup.java` with

```
public IControl iControl = null;
```

and runs `onCreateView` and here

```
iControl.status(true);
```

refers to null objet.

To fix that, i suggest to customize the constructor of `Popup` class by adding an `Icontrol` parameter, something like that

```
private final Popup mPopup = new Popup(R.layout.fragment_dialog, this);
```

and edit the `Popup.java` file